# Converting shares from the chemical disassociation equation into fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Some basic math is eluding me when trying to derive a simple disassociation constant formula.

Given that $K_d=\frac{[A][B]}{[AB]}$, $[A]+[AB]=[A_0]$, $[B]+[AB]=[B_0]$, and $[B_0] \gg [A_0]$ I'm trying to find $[A]/[A_0]$ for a given $[B]$.  My dirty derivation follows:

$$ \begin{align}
K_d &= \frac{[A][B]}{[AB]}=\frac{[A][B_0]}{[AB]}\\
\frac{K_d}{[B_0]} &= \frac{[A]}{[AB]}\\
\end{align}$$

Here I have apparently lost my precalc marbles and revert to a more complicated, probably less rigorous method.  Basically, I figure that the numerators and denominators on each side are proportional to each other using some arbitrary constant $k$, so I then use those proportions to calculate the ratio to the total pool of $[A]$

$$
\frac{K_d}{[B_0]} = \frac{[A]}{[AB]} \rightarrow [A] = k K_d, [AB] = k[B_0]\\
\frac{[A]}{[A_0]} = \frac{[A]}{[AB] + [A]} = \frac{kK_d}{k[B_0] + kK_d} = \frac{K_d}{[B_0]+K_d}
$$

This feels overly complicated like I'm missing an obvious path.

Comment: Are you meaning $[B] \gg [A]$ or $[B_0] \gg [A_0]$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the latter...corrected.

Answer (score 1):

From the balance equation for $A$, $[A]+[AB]=[A_0]$, you have $[AB]=[A_0]-[A]$; then, from the balance equation for $B$, $[B]+[AB]=[B_0]$, you  have $[B]=[B_0]-[AB]=[B_0]-[A_0]+[A]$ so the equilibrium equation write $$K_d=\frac{[A][B]}{[AB]}=\frac{[A]([B_0]-[A_0]+[A])}{[A_0]-[A]}$$ Now,since $[B_0] \gg [A_0]$, $[B_0]-[A_0]+[A] \simeq [B_0]$ and then $$K_d \simeq \frac{[A][B_0]}{[A_0]-[A]}$$ to be solved as a function of $[A]$. Doing so, you will arrive to your result $$
\frac{[A]}{[A_0]} \simeq \frac{K_d}{[B_0]+K_d}$$ If you do not take into account the condition $[B_0] \gg [A_0]$, you just need to solve three equations for three unknowns $[A],[B],[AB]$ which reduce to a quadratic equation.